How to intercept notifications on iOS and save data in shared_preferences
I am trying to add a chat ability in my app. I wanted to have all the messages and chats locally saved on the Android/iOS device where the app can load from when being opened. The idea is that I will need my Laravel app to notify other devices if a new message is sent, or deleted, or a user being removed/added to a group and so on. I tried using silent notifications (data messages).
On Android, because there is no much throttling or battery optimizations, every data message is being delivered successfully but on iOS, messages are being throttled due to battery optimizations and the OS can't let my app run in the background more than few times before a cooldown is being put on the app, so updating the local data on iOS cannot depend on data messages at all. I need a robust way of communicating between Laravel and Flutter.
I tried asking on apple developers forums and got this answer from one of apple's engineers:

Background notifications to wake up your app to run some code will be throttled.
I suggest looking into using a Notification Service Extension as discussed at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension. The NotificationService Extension will be executed for every visible push notification. So, it could serve your needs, as long as the user has not disabled the visibility of your notifications through various settings. The service extension will not be executed for push notifications that will not be presented visually.
Although the designed purpose of this expansion is to modify the incoming messages, so whether it will fit your use case or not, you will have to decide yourself.
The extension will be limited to 30 seconds and 24 MB total memory. You cannot directly communicate with your main app except via a shared container you can write and read. And you cannot send silent notifications.

this gave me an idea of sending normal notifications with unique ids to avoid notifications collapsing and ensure delivery reliability. The other problem is to save the data locally where I can use shared prefrences to save data and then when the app starts, I will convert these data and add them into my local database. I am not familar with swift so I had chatgpt for help in the code but didn't know why is it not working.
import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {
var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    print("NSE: didReceive triggered")
    
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)
    
    guard let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent else {
        print("NSE: bestAttemptContent is nil")
        contentHandler(request.content)
        return
    }

    print("NSE: Notification Payload - \(request.content.userInfo)")
    
    if let userInfo = request.content.userInfo as? [String: Any],
       let suppressFlag = userInfo["suppress"] as? Bool,
       let cleanData = userInfo["data"] as? [String: Any] {
        print("NSE: Suppress flag = \(suppressFlag)")
        
        if suppressFlag {
            print("NSE: Suppressing notification")
            bestAttemptContent.title = ""
            bestAttemptContent.body = ""
            bestAttemptContent.sound = nil
        } else {
            print("NSE: Displaying notification")
            bestAttemptContent.title = cleanData["title"] as? String ?? "New Message"
            bestAttemptContent.body = cleanData["body"] as? String ?? "You have a new message."
        }

        print("NSE: Saving notification to shared container")
        saveNotificationToSharedContainer(data: cleanData)
    }

    print("NSE: Passing modified content to handler")
    contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
}

override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
    // Called when time runs out
    if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}

private func saveNotificationToSharedContainer(data: [String: Any]) {
    // Access shared container
    let sharedDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.egensolve.demo")
    var notifications = sharedDefaults?.array(forKey: "stored_notifications") as? [[String: Any]] ?? []

    // Append the new notification data
    notifications.append(data)
    sharedDefaults?.set(notifications, forKey: "stored_notifications")
    sharedDefaults?.synchronize()
}
}

for more clarification, the code was supposed to see if a suppress key is sent with value of true/false. if true, then I wanted to NOT show the notification as it is supposedly of no importance to view it. if false, then show it. ChatGPT also guided me to create an app group and said to add it to both the NSE and Main targets, so I did.
code for sending a notification for an Android/iOS device:
public function sendDataMessage($deviceTokens, $data = [], $priority = "high")
{
    $messaging = app('firebase.messaging');
    $clean_data = $data;
    if (isset($data["type"]) && $data["type"] == "chat" && $data["action"] == "receiveMessage") {
        unset($clean_data["fcm_message"]);
    }
    $messages = [];
    foreach ($deviceTokens as $token) {
        $aps = [];
        try {
            if (isset($data["type"]) && $data["type"] == "chat") {
                $chat_message = $data["fcm_message"];
                $clean_data["title"] = Chats::select("name")->find($data["chat_id"])->name;
                if ($data["action"] == "receiveMessage") {
                    $clean_data["body"] = $chat_message["sender"]["name"] . ": " . ($chat_message["content"]["type"] == "Text" ? $chat_message["content"]["body"] : $chat_message["content"]["type"]);
                    $aps = [
                        "alert" => [
                            "title" => $clean_data["title"],
                            "body" => $clean_data["body"]
                        ],
                        "content-available" => 1,
                        "mutable-content" => 1
                    ];
                    $clean_data["suppress"] = true;
                    $aps["sound"] = "default";
                } else {
                    $clean_data["suppress"] = true;
                }
            }
            $messages[] = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $token)
                ->withData($clean_data)
                ->withAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig::fromArray([
                    'priority' => 'normal',  // Use high priority
                    'ttl' => 86400 * 28, // 4 weeks in seconds
                ]))
                ->withApnsConfig(ApnsConfig::fromArray([
                    'headers' => [
                        'apns-collapse-id' => uniqid(),
                        'apns-expiration' => strval(time() + 86400 * 28), // Expiry timestamp
                        'apns-priority' => '10',
                    ],
                    'payload' => [
                        'aps' => $aps,
                    ],
                ]));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
    }
    try {
        $report = $messaging->sendAll($messages);
    } catch (NotFound $e) {
        return $e;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }

    return $report->successes()->count();
}

Reading from shared prefs:
final notifications = prefs?.getStringList('stored_notifications') ?? [];
print(notifications);


You keep asking similar questions and we keep telling you that notifications are not a good solution for this.  They are limited, best effort and not guaranteed delivery.

sorry for multiple questions, I wanted to add the response from 1 of the engineers at Apple but thought it wasn't related to other questions. I am just desperate for a way on how to make my app always keep up to date with my server without on app start request to fetch data from server. If you have another idea other than notifications please tell, I don't know how Whatsapp does it, it doesn't need internet connection once a message is received, and it doesn't have a cool down for data messages. I can't think of another way @Paulw11

I also tried to go through Signal app's open source code but couldn't determine its way of keeping app up to date.

Signal seems to use a combination of background motivations, regular alert notifications and updating its database when it returns to the foreground.

I am confused by one thing that you said; "sending normal notifications with unique ids to avoid notifications collapsing and ensure delivery reliability"; every notification should have a unique id unless it is an update. For example a notification telling you that a flight is boarding in 5 mins and a later notification telling you that it is now boarding should have the same apns-collapse-id because the old notification is no longer valid. A notification telling you that a user has sent a message would have a unique apns-collapse-id because you want them stacked.

And yes, you can use a notification service extension to fetch some data as long as notifications are enabled.
